# testing cURL the code not working

Tags: php, curl

Why is this curl  code not returning any thing as it was working while I tried for my local testing site.

```
public function test_curl()
{

    //step1
    $cSession = curl_init(); 
    //step2
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/search?q=hehe");
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    //step3
    $result=curl_exec($cSession);
    //step4
    curl_close($cSession);
    //step5
    echo $result;


    }
```

Comment: If it was working for you somewhere else, then figure out what is different between your 'local testing site' and wherever you're now trying to run it. Configuration differences can be causing errors; check your logs etc.

Comment: You may want to do actual error checking to discover the issue. And enable error_reporting and display_errors, as both are likely disabled or reduced on a production site.

Comment: well the local testing site means I have tried to do this with a web page in that is in my wamp server

Comment: ok I will try the error_reporting and dispaly_errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
$URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=hehe";    
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL); 
$result =curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

It works on sites that have blocked file_get_contents. Should do the trick!

Comment: it worked but what really was the problem in my code can you please explain

Comment: No not really. I believe, you must use a agent when curling but not sure.