# cURL and get_file_contents blocked

Tags: php, curl

I know this question has been dealt with on a few occasions but none of the fixes seem to work with my particular problem.
I am trying to grab any page from http://www.lewmar.com but some how they are managing to block all attempts. My latest script is as follows:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
  {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $browser_id = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0";

    $ip = $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser_id);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ip);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$url = 'http://www.lewmar.com';
$contents = curl_get_contents($url);
echo strlen($contents);
```

I have tried to replicate most of the headers and the site doesn't seem to check for 'Javascript' compatibility but yet still can't get anything returned.

Does anyone have any idea how they might be recognizing cURL and blocking.

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288640/testing-curl-the-code-not-working/34290456#34290456

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work on this particular site.

Answer (score 0):

When you first visit that site it checks to see if you have a cookie. If you don't, it will send you one and send a redirect (to the same page). You haven't got anything in your code to store cookies so you end up going round in a circle. Curl gives up after 20 redirects. Solution: enable cookies!

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies2.txt');

Comment: Thanks, I've added the additional headers and run the script again.  I can see a new cookie is written to cookies.txt as follows:   

# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

www.lewmar.com FALSE / FALSE 1491653865 Drupal.visitor.commerce_currency GBP

cookies2.txt does not get created and I still get nothing returned from curl.

I'm not great with cookies so maybe I'm missing something really simple?

Comment: I also took out CURLOPT_REFERER, so maybe try that?