# php curl does not work for a given url on a given php server

Tags: php, curl

I download a page using PHP as follows, and it works (both in my development computer, and in our production PHP server):

```
$url = "http://google.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo strlen($content);
```

However, for the url "https://invue.com/patents/" it only works from my development computer, but not from the production PHP server (`strlen($content)` returns `0`).

Any idea of what can be the problem, or how to find out the problem?

Comment: anything from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: Could be a lot. Maybe your production  ip got blocked?

Comment: try this `if($content === false){   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); }` if there is any error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288640/testing-curl-the-code-not-working/34290456

Comment: Are you calling the same domain?

Comment: @jagad89, curl_error showed the problem, thx! it was: Curl error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate. Please post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For curl failure, you can use function `curl_error`

```
$url = "http://google.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
// check, Did something go wrong !?
if($content === false){ 
  // This will show what's wrong.
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); 
}
curl_close($ch);
echo strlen($content);
```

For more information curl_error