# web scraping does not work only on this site

Tags: php, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm using the same code to get the price of different web pages (7 in particular), all work perfect, but in 1 I can not get any data, could you tell me if it is impossible, if the page has any protection? Thanks in advance.

```
$source = file_get_contents("https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/Computo-Hardware/Discos-Duros-SSD-NAS/Discos-Duros-Internos-para-PC/Disco-Duro-Interno-Western-Digital-Caviar-Blue-3-5-1TB-SATA-III-6-Gbit-s-7200RPM-64MB-Cache.html");

preg_match("'<span class=\"priceText\">(.*?)</span>'", $source, $price);

echo $price[1];
```

I hope this result:
$869.00

This code only works badly on the website shown in the code.

Comment: some websites have anti scrapping feature like Amazon that doesn't allow to scrape data.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad In fact this code (changing classes) if it allows me to obtain data from Amazon.

Comment: You need to turn on error_reporting and pay attention to the warning messages which are very interesting; see https://3v4l.org/LM1il. The problem apparently indeed relates to the specific website and the protection(s) they have in place.

Comment: @slevy1 Those warnings are just a limitation of the sandbox you're using.

Comment: I don't think 3v4l allow file_get_contents. But OP try and use curl instead that usually works when a page has protection like that.

Comment: @DavidNoriega see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288640/testing-curl-the-code-not-working/34290456#34290456

Comment: @andreas hace I'm running the code and the google page appears (which I've never tried to be honest) but how can I implement this in my code? I think we're on the right path, something tells me that.

Comment: Using regex to parse html, is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curl with an agent set, this usually tricks the website protections to believe it's a true user.

```
$URL = "https://www.cyberpuerta.mx/Computo-Hardware/Discos-Duros-SSD-NAS/Discos-Duros-Internos-para-PC/Disco-Duro-Interno-Western-Digital-Caviar-Blue-3-5-1TB-SATA-III-6-Gbit-s-7200RPM-64MB-Cache.html";

$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL); 
$result =curl_exec($ch);
preg_match("'<span class=\"priceText\">(.*?)</span>'", $result, $price);

echo $price[1];
```

Comment: You just helped the wrong person. Please read: https://www.seo-theory.com/the-difference-between-a-good-crawler-and-a-spammy-rogue-crawler/ You might disagree with this, but it is a valid opinion. Reflect on your morals please.

Comment: @Software KIKO This is a personal project which will never be online, I will use it for my own business locally, when I quote a piece that a client asks me, I have to open 8 pages to compare prices, in this way I will save a lot of time. I understand the concern but it is for personal (non-commercial) purposes.

Comment: @DavidNoriega You are not the only reader of this answer. Anyway, it's the principle, not about you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware haven't read it all but I saw the thing about being a parasite and believing you have the right to others data and so on... Is that what you are arguing? What makes you think that is always the case? I have a crawler myself and I have written agreements with all pages I crawl.

Comment: The point is that you help crawler bots lie about their identity. This is bad for a website in any way thinkable. Don't be lazy, read the article and learn. @DavidNoriega Ultimately yes, although the mistake wasn't yours.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have read it now and it's quite obvious it's a grumpy person who wrote it. Nowhere does he mention any exceptions like agreements or websites that do allow even if they have those safety features or that you can contact the owner. If you want to make an article credible than at least show both sides of the coin and say there might be exceptions to the rules

Comment: Ha ha, yes, very grumpy. The idea to contact the web master it there, although not explicit. Nobody ever asks for permission anyway. That's probably what made him grumpy. The point is, of course, that the web is awash with crawlers lying about their identity and that this screws with websites. It's a free for all, except for the website owner.

Comment: I also just finished reading the article and I'm not 100% agree, it's simple: Forces your users to log in and if necessary, pay a fee for reading that valuable content that you do not want anyone to see (or better yet ... not to publish it on the internet), in my case, I generate thousands of profits to my suppliers for selling their products, I do not think they get angry for making my work times shorter and buying more.

Comment: @DavidNoriega Then why is it that you have to lie about the identity of your crawler? In other words; Even a mass murderer can find a justification for the deed, that doesn't make it right. (BTW, I don't want to compare your to a mass murderer, it's just to emphasis that a good excuse doesn't excuse bad behavior).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware and then there is the old saying. Don't put stuff on the internet that you don't want people to steal.

Comment: Tell that to the Europeans! (see: https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-47239600). But I agree with that one, you cannot copy protect web content. Any attempt at that is doomed. But you clearly still misunderstand, I am not talking about content, I am talking about traffic.

Comment: hahaha good already we stop this, they need to vote to erase or not this crime: 1 or 0?

Comment: @DavidNoriega For me discussing it is enough, you don't need to delete the crime. (Am I allowed to change my mind?)

Comment: @Andreas Could you help me again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718569/web-scraping-with-curl-in-walmart-not-work